# Can't delete file - rm returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: debian

I'm trying to delete a file with the command:

```
rm -rIf cifs1bd7
```

It returns the error:

> No such file or directory

But the file does exist, I can see it with the command `ls` and I can autocomplete it. It just seems like I've no right on it but I'm root. I've tried many things but nothing works so far... Any ideas?

Comment: try running it with sudo

Comment: But I'm already root.

Comment: That was the first measure as most of the time sudo is the answer. however have you tried running it with sudo... try using only 'sudo rm -r filename'

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was necessary to run it with sudo even though I was using root user :

```
sudo rm -rIf cifs1bd7
```